# Set the MaxClockSkew when using NetTcpBinding with TransportWithMessageCredential

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm using WCF with the NetTcpBinding and I'm unable to set the MaxClockSkew as the SymmetricSecurityBindingElement is null when using SecurityMode of TransportWithMessageCrediential. Does anyone know how this is done when using TransportWithMessageCrediential SecurityMode?

```
    private Binding GetNetTcpBinding()
    {
        long MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        int MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        int MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        int MaxNameTableCharCount = 100000;
        var timeout = 5;
        var maxClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);

        var binding = new NetTcpBinding
        {
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout),
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout),
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxReceivedMessageSize,
            ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
            {
                MaxArrayLength = MaxBytesPerRead,
                MaxBytesPerRead = MaxBytesPerRead,
                MaxNameTableCharCount = MaxNameTableCharCount,
                MaxStringContentLength = MaxStringContentLength,
                MaxDepth = MaxBytesPerRead
            }
        };

        binding.ReliableSession = new OptionalReliableSession
        {
            Enabled = true,
            InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout),
            Ordered = true
        };

        binding.Security = new NetTcpSecurity
        {
            Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
            Message = new MessageSecurityOverTcp
            {
                ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate,
                AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256
            },
            Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity
            {
                ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate,
                SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
            }
        };

        var customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);

        var security =
            customBinding.Elements.Find<SymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();

        //  NOTE: This Always Returns NULL
        if (security != null)
        {
            security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = maxClockSkew;
            security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = maxClockSkew;

            // Get the System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters 
            var secureTokenParams =
                (SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)security.ProtectionTokenParameters;

            // From the collection, get the bootstrap element.
            var bootstrap = secureTokenParams.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;

            // Set the MaxClockSkew on the bootstrap element.
            bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = maxClockSkew;
            bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = maxClockSkew;

            return customBinding;
        }

        return binding;
    }
```

I'm unable to find any solutions for this and the documentation seems to be out of date. This only works if you use SecurityMode.Message.